# Get x and y value of a series in highcharts when curve is being plotted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using a custom formatter for yAxis in highcharts. The following gives me the current y axis value:

```
yAxis: {
     labels:{
           formatter: function(){
                            return this.value
                      }
             }
}
```

Is there a way that I can also access the coordinate's x-axis value, and z-axis value inside the formatter function? I can get all the values, but not the corresponding x, and z values.

Comment: What do you mean by corresponding values? Do you mean, that you also want to display x value of a point with the same y value as the label? If so, you can achieve it the similar way as in the following example. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4trobd4t/.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check the chart object from console like this;

```
yAxis: {
   labels:{
       formatter: function(){
                        console.log(this);
                  }
         }
}
```

You can find any needed value in this object. For example; `this.chart.xAxis[0].categories[0]` will give you the value of first element on xAxis.